# Confusion regarding uniqueness of Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> Assuming a Levi-Civita connection exists it is uniquely determined.
>   Using $\nabla g = 0$ and the symmetry of the metric tensor $g$ we
>   find:
>
> $ X (g(Y,Z)) + Y (g(Z,X)) - Z (g(Y,X)) = g(\nabla_X Y + \nabla_Y X, Z) + g(\nabla_X Z - \nabla_Z X, Y) + g(\nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Z Y, X). $

I am not sure how this is concluded. Can anyone elaborate further on here? I just can't see the link between left side and right side...

Comment: To using koszul formula.

Comment: The connection also needs to be torsion free to get uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

The Levi-Civita connection satisfies

$$
X \, g(Y, Z) = g(\nabla_X Y, Z) + g(Y, \nabla_X Z).
$$

This, together with the symmetry of $g$, is sufficient to check that relation.